# Td align deprecated....then what to use for html inline for emails

Tags: html, css, email

Wow I feel outdated! I have been using the align and valign attribute to align data in tables for our html campaigns. Let me preceed this by saying that we do data intensive emails for finance. I know I know....we are not about standards :)

so all the examples I have been seeing are to style the cells via css like so

```
td {
   text-align:left;

}
```

Well in emails we cannot do that, we have to use line styles like this:

```
 <td style="text-align:left;">
```

Now since our emails have data intensive tables(i,e, performance tables)

Am I supposed to now style each cell like above?

There are a tremendous amount of cells. Like 100 in total. As you can imagine this would take forever and in our industry clients want things so fast its absurd. So using dreamweaver i can just select the cells and align them. Boom done!

but is that correct? if so, how can i do this quickly?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: _"Am I supposed to now style each cell like above?"_ Yup.

Comment: For `HTML` table-based emails, you can still use `<td align="right">` or `<td align="left">`

Comment: Karthkir...i did see that answer but writing it external as opposed to inline threw me. and the author mainly talks about browsers which is different in my case. This is more for email clients.

j08691 - haha thats a lot of styles to do :(

Comment: All these are useful....and I hate emails!!! :)

thanks!!!!! very much appreiciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS text-align is not always consistent across major email clients. Always align cells like this for 100% consistency:

```
<td align="left">
```

By default, everything is left aligned anyway, so you only need to worry about it if center or right aligning.

Comment: Good I thought I was correct in using the align attribute. A coworker mentioned that it was deprecated and I was like, uh well wth am I supposed to do now :)

Comment: Depreciated in web usually means the best way to do it in html email...

Answer (score 1):

Use `td` elements in for email as Outlook doesn't play well with `div`s

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3572/email-rendering-issues-and-fixes-for-outlook-web-app-owa/